# Background-image behind Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a Bootstrap carousel working fine, but I want to add a background image *behind* this carousel, the background image at width 100 %, and inside the image, covering 80% of the image, having the carousel working. 
I've tried having background-image in my #homecarousel's CSS, I've tried some tricky position:absolute manipulations (which are not a good idea anyway), I've checked the already existing posts around, but nothing works…
Basically it's just a small rectange inside a big rectangle, and the small rectangle is a carousel…
Any idea ?
I would prefer a pure CSS solution to a Javascript manipulation, because I didn't program 90% of the site, just taking it now and it's all a mess of files so I would prefer touching as few as I can.
Many thanks

Comment: share your html and css code demo with jsfiddle

Comment: please provide your code with jsfiddle or snippet..

Comment: sorry yes, here is what my code looks like : http://codepen.io/jgrandsenne/pen/aNGQrP // It already works better than on the real website (i changed the pictuers) can it simply be a matter of image size in the original file ?

Comment: Your markup must be here. Markup on third party sites can, and do, disappear and of no help to future visitors looking for the same help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go , i hope this was what you needed ?

http://codepen.io/DasithKuruppu/pen/MyGZdd

Basically i changed

```
carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img, .img-responsive,  .thumbnail a>img, .thumbnail>img {

        width: 80%;
        /* left: 50%; */
        margin-left: 10%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

^ This sets the inner image of carousel to a width of 80% of the container and sets a margin left of 10% which would mean it would be centered horizontally

And as for the background image i set it to cover instead of contain, cover stretches the background image to the far corners which may change the original aspect ratio of image unlike contain.

Comment: thank you so much, it's really almost this, except the image must be centered both in width and height, and when i change the height parameters i don't get anything relevant… can you tell ?

Comment: As you have figured out already centering image with a space vertically is almost the same as horizontally by setting a margin-top and margin-bottom. Please do mark an answer as the correct answer if it solved your issue, http://codepen.io/DasithKuruppu/pen/pyVmdz

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED Answer**

How about this https://jsfiddle.net/rzc1e1jf/ ? (Note that at the external resources I added the bootstrap basics)

I started from scratch this time and it seems to be working fine.

---

**Previous answer**

I am not 100% sure I understood your question correctly, but is this what you are trying to achieve:

http://codepen.io/andrasadam93/pen/BKxvRZ

```
#carousel-container {
    background-image: url('http://portfoliotheme.org/enigmatic/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2012/07/placeholder1.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
}


#homecarousel {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10%;
    width: 80%;
    height:100%;
}
.carousel-inner {
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: i actually need the kitten to be a carousel, centered in the middle of a not-moving background-image

Comment: I added a new JS Fiddle, I guess that is what you were looking for!

Comment: Your edited markup must be posted here as third-party postings can, and do, disappear making your answer useless to future visitors.

Comment: Will do that Rob, as soon as the discussion has ended.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's solved, many thanks to Dasith Kuruppu, and to center vertically as well it's as I thought from you code, you just do the same with up and bottom, the reason why it wasn't working was simply a conflict with another declaration. So here it is :

```
.carousel-inner>.item>a>img, .carousel-inner>.item>img {

width: 90%;
/* left: 50%; */
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
height: 90% ;
margin-bottom:5%;
margin-top: 5%;
}
```

Many thanks